# Flask Python: Sending form data with Flask mail

Tags: python, html, flask

I there a smooth way on how to send html form data with flask mail?

I am trying to get the input from the user from my contact.html.

```
{% block content %}
<h1 class="title">
  Contact Us
</h1>
<form action="/contact" method="POST">
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input is-large" type="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" autofocus="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input is-large" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="textarea is-large" type="text" name="message" placeholder="How can we help you?">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Contact us</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the main.py @route for this page and the code that CAN send an email but i am not able to format it so it also sends the input from the user.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash
from flask_login import FlaskLoginClient, login_required, current_user
from . import db
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    MAIL_PORT = 587,
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True,
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False,
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'mymail@mail.com',
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
))

mail = Mail(app)

@main.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')

@main.route('/contact', methods=["POST"])
def contact_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        message = request.form.get('message')
        msg = Message('Test', sender='mymail@mail.com', recipients=['mymai@mail.com'])
        msg.body = 'Test mail from:'
        mail.send(msg)
        return 'done'
```

After adding the code that is referenced below 'msg.body = "Contact form submitted with data:\n\nName: {}\n\nE-mail: {}\n\nMessage: {}".format(name, email, message)' i now get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/project/main.py", line 38, in contact_post
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 416, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 351, in send
    connection.send(self)
  File "/home/MyPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 166, in send
    self.host.sendmail(message.sender,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 875, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe5' in position 396: ordinal not in range(128)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2022 09:45:13] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

After the update to Flask-Mail version 0.9.1 i get these errors.

```
[2022-07-10 15:08:23,600] ERROR in app: Exception on /contact [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/project/main.py", line 38, in contact_post
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
    connection.send(self)
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 190, in send
    message.as_bytes() if PY3 else message.as_string(),
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 385, in as_bytes
    return self._message().as_bytes()
  File "/home/myPC/repos/Flask-app/flaskappy/auth/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 307, in _message
    ascii_attachments = current_app.extensions['mail'].ascii_attachments
KeyError: 'mail'
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2022 15:08:23] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the posted information to the mail, assuming you want it to the mail body, you could format the `msg.body` as:

```
msg.body = "Contact form submitted with data:\n\nName: {}\n\nE-mail: {}\n\nMessage: {}".format(name, email, message)
```

you can use `msg.html` to provide html formatted body if you wish to.

Comment: Thank you for the respons, your answer seems clever and i have added that code to my project, but i am now getting Error Code 500 with the following message:
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe5' in position 396: ordinal not in range(128)"
It seems quiet fatal.... what does this mean?

Comment: Is that coming from some code not shown in your question? Would help if you could show which line causes it.

Comment: Which version of Flask-mail are you using? i am searching in the flask-mail code for the line `self.host.sendmail(message.sender,` from your log and i dont see it, i suspect you have an older one. i am using `Flask-Mail==0.9.1` and i cannot reproduce your errorm when i feed non-ASCII characters in the mail message, the mail gets sent fine.

Comment: The problem is solved your 1st answer helped, the problem is specific and hard to explain i feel that i don't need to explain everything in detail since it was caused by human(me) error.